# Matlab find closest function from plot

Tags: matlab, random, plot

[image]

I have a probability distribution of some datasets. I have drawn this from the datasets in matlab. The question is that I want to generate similar data with these. I want to get the approximate function in this graph so that I can use it to generate new numbers. Is there a way to make this? either getting the nearest function of that plot OR some other suggestion to make this is appreciated.

EDIT: I have added the plot

A more general question that may be little more useful can be that
Given that there are some random variables I need an algorithm, software, technique to get similar random variable numbers.

I can understand that artificial intelligence techniques can be useful in this but I am wondering if there is a simple question. Possibly (my ai knowledge is not that good) some neural network or markov chain model can make this job but I believe that could be done easier. The function that I want is probability distribution function. I have 3 datasets and they are consistent with each other. They have very similar distributions.

Comment: check about curve fitting. Check the basic fitting option under Tools menu bar.

Comment: I will give you an upvote so you can post images. There are many ways to estimate probability density functions, both parametric and non-parametric. You can use MLE for parametric specifications and kernel density estimators, or k-harmonic means, or EM for non-parametric specifications.

Comment: Another upvote - post what you have...

Comment: You can generate new data with the same distribution without worrying about fitting a function. Namely, generate a random number x between 0 and 1, uniformly. From your  data, pick the value such that x proportion of all data points are below it. That's it. (It matlab terms: sort the array V of known values from smallest to largest; the look near the index 1+floor(x*numel(V)) and interpolate.

Comment: I would try to fit it into exponential or (part of a) gaussian distribution

Comment: Could you add plot with log Y scale?

Comment: Basically, numbers around 0 might be wildly different, but they are all look about the same on the graphs. So if you plot log(P) vs duration, you might uncover that your data fits well with straight line - ergo, you have exponential distribution and from the line you could pick parameters and do the events sampling